# Accessing values from partial classes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

Please help! I'm still learning so this might be completely wrong. I have built a multi-user web application for internal purposes. I have split my code up to make it more manageable and have run into some problems. I suspect that I have done something very silly!

I have a class in a separate file (quoteStatus.vb) in App_Code here it is:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class quoteStatusHelper

 Public Shared QuoteStatus As String

    Public Shared Sub GetQuoteStatus(ByVal QuoteID As String)

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("quotingSystemConnectionString")
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM Quote WHERE QuoteID =" & QuoteID & ";"
            Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While lrd.Read()
                QuoteStatus = lrd("Status")
            End While

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub
    End Class
```

I use this to fire the code from another file:

```
quoteStatusHelper.GetQuoteStatus(QuoteID)
```

Then grab the result with

```
Dim returnedStatus = quoteStatusHelper.QuoteStatus
```

This seems really wrong, as the value seems to be held in the partial class after the first run. So if I have two users accessing the class the public shared dim is changed for both users! There must be a better way to do this. I have looked everywhere and I'm more confused now than when I started off...

How can I make QuoteStatus in the partial class unique to every user and access it from my code. I cant figure it out :( Please help

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if the QuoteID passed into GetQuoteStatus method is "1; Delete From Quote Where QuoteID > 1"? Note: Don't try it, just warning against SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the heads up. Injection is something that I am aware of but as yet I havent learnt how to avoid it. Although this app will be a system only open to specific people via IP restrictions on IIS I am keen to know what I can do to avoid this in the future. Many thanks

Comment: Is the line `quoteSelectHelper.GetQuoteInfo(QuoteID)` actually that or should it be `quoteStatusHelper.GetQuoteInfo(QuoteID)`?

Comment: Hi @Chris yes sorry that was a typo... well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `QuoteStatus` variable is  shared/static. You don't need to do that here. Declaring it as Public will make it visible to other classes. Remove `Shared` from the method and the `QuoteStaus` variable, and all should be well.

Once you remove `Shared` it will be an instance class, which means that you'll need to initialize it in your code:

```
Dim statusHelper As New quoteStatusHelper()
statusHelper.GetQuoteStatus("QuoteID")
```

**EDIT**

Taking a closer look at your code, it looks like you could make `GetQuoteStatus` a function that returns the `QuoteStatus` as a string, as @Claudio Redi suggested.

```
Public Function GetQuoteStatus(ByVal QuoteID As String) As String 

    Dim quoteStatus As String

    Dim con As New SqlConnection  
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand  

    Try  
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("quotingSystemConnectionString")  
        con.Open()  
        cmd.Connection = con  
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM Quote WHERE QuoteID =" & QuoteID & ";"  
        Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()  

        While lrd.Read()  
            quoteStatus = lrd("Status")  
        End While  

    Catch ex As Exception  

    Finally  
        con.Close()  
    End Try  

    Return quoteStatus

End Function
```

By making `GetQuoteStatus` a function, you'll be able to get the value like this:

```
Dim statusHelper As New quoteStatusHelper()
Dim quoteStatus As String = statusHelper.GetQuoteStatus("QuoteID")
```

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for editing my bad english and novice programming talk! I wasnt sure which 'shared' to remove so I tried them one by one and im getting:
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Thank you for your help

Comment: Remove `Shared` from the `QuoteStatus` variable too.

Comment: Ahh ok. I have changed all Public Shared to just Public in the file but now I have another problem... When I use 'dim something = quoteStatusHelper.QuoteStatus' in another file I get an error: 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.' How can I overcome this? Many thanks!

Comment: See my edited answer. I included code to show you how to initialize an instance of `quoteStatusHelper`.

Comment: AHA! Thanks for laying it out for me james... workes perfectly! 6hrs trying to figure it out myself and just a few mins on here and all is solved. Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

An option would be using a local variable on your method for `quoteStatus` and using it as return value of `GetQuoteStatus`. So you wouldn't use anymore the shared member `QuoteStatus`

**EDIT**

Added a function example. You should remove your shared member `QuoteStatus` from your class. I don't use VB on my day to day work so I hope I didn't make any stupid syntax mistake

```
Public Shared Function GetQuoteStatus(ByVal QuoteID As String) as String

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim quoteStatus As String

    Try
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("quotingSystemConnectionString")
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM Quote WHERE QuoteID =" & QuoteID & ";"
        Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While lrd.Read()
            quoteStatus = lrd("Status")
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    return quoteStatus

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Claudio, Thank you for your help. Please can you give me an example of how to do this? Sorry im still at the very early stages of learning...